# How to access "/h2-console" in Spring Boot with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I searched some codes that disable csrf so that I can access "/h2-console", but they don't seem to work. when I enter "/h2-console", the logIn prompt still appears Just like before I wrote this code

what is the problem?

I want to access h2 database with no logIn prompt

this is the Security Config code, and the image is file structure(intellij)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkhNI.png)

```
package com.taxiWithBack.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePwd(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll();


        return http.build();
    }

    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(encodePwd().encode("password")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password(encodePwd().encode("password")).roles("ADMIN");

    }






}

enter image description here
```

Comment: Enable spring security DEBUG logs and update your question to include them so that we can see the actual reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see that there is approximately any problem with your code. And I made some changes to your code and ran it myself and it worked successfully.So this is my Security Config class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users",
                                "/h2-console/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails anar = User.builder()
                .username("test1")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("test1"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        UserDetails rufat = User.builder()
                .username("test2")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("test2"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(anar, rufat);
    }
}
```

I hope you didn't forget to write the following in the application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try and modify your code to this and validate the same:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll() // permits access to all URLs starting with /h2-console/ without authentication.
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();

        // disables the X-Frame-Options header to allow the H2 console to be displayed in an iframe
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("password")).roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder.encode("password")).roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encodePwd() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Note:

- extending **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** allows us to override the
  **configure(HttpSecurity http)** method to define security rules.
- this configuration should be used for dev purpose, not for prod, as
  it removes many security features and may leave your application
  vulnerable.

Comment: First, thank you for answering, but there's a problem. "Cannot resolve symbol 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'", this is error message from intellij. Actually I already found "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" while I was searching some codes to solve this problem but THAT IS DEPRECATED from 5.7.0-M2 so I posted this question .. (https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated and removed in spring security 6 so this answer is not correct.